# Any good, visual HTML5 Editor or IDE?

Tags: ide, editor, html, html-editor

Well it looks like Dreamweaver CS5 will try to smoother the HTML5 thing for a few more years (weeks actually). Seems like the next rung down is right to Notepad!

Anyone know a good HTML5 editor with a visual/preview/style leaning?

Eclipse with some pluggin?

(Seems like the market will be begging for it soon.)

Thanks

*...By the way. I know about the 'no browser support'...'not finished yet'..etc. That's not an issue for us. We are doing Safari Only websites & iPhone iAd's only production...So we know what works in our implementations.
(We mostly on Windows by the way)*

Comment: Wow look another question closed as "off topic" with 174K in views and lots of good answers! Glad to see it's not just mine...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Cloud 9 IDE](https://c9.io/site/features/). Storage is cloud+local, it offers autocompletion, it provides explicit support for node.js development, offers real-time collaboration, and you get bash into the deal with all its most popular tools (gcc included). All without having to open anything other than your browser.

I think that's Pretty Awesome.

**EDIT Q3 2013** I would also suggest JetBrains WebStorm. It has autocompletion and solid refactoring features for HTML5, CSS3, JS. And it is very responsive.

Comment: [Cloud 9 IDE new link](https://c9.io/)

Answer (score 39):

I always liked Aptana Studio for HTML development. [Aptana Studio 3 beta](http://aptana.com/products/studio3) supports the latest HTML5 specifications and is quite fast (compared to version 2). There is a standalone and an Eclipse pug-in version available.
UPDATE: Final release available (same link)

Comment: +1 for Aptana Studio 3 beta. It is quite a nice IDE and it is cross-platform.

Comment: UPDATE: Out of beta and first Bugfix-release, right now: http://aptana.com/products/studio3/releasenotes

Comment: Besides visual/WYSIWYG on HTML5 tags feature, I wish to have IDE that aware of HTML5 API like  Web Storage API etc, when I type window <dot>, the sessionStorage and localStorage etc object autocompletion do not appear...

Comment: Ah, "pug-ins". Puggins would make a great surname. Thanks for the laugh.

Answer (score 10):

### **Update**

Use **[Aptana Studio 3](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download)**, it's upgraded now.

You can either choose

- Standalone Version
- [Eclipse Plug-in Version](http://www.aptana.com/downloads/start)

Try online [Aloha WYSIWYG Editor](http://www.aloha-editor.org/)

But as a web-developer, I still prefer **Notepad++**, it has necessary code assists.

---

### Outdated info, please don't refer.

---

This might be late answer, yeah very late answer, but surely will help someone
Download **"Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers"** [Latest Stable Version](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)
 
Download [Google Plugin for Eclipse.zip](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip) 
Select your download according to your **Eclipse Version**
 After Downloading (*don't Unzip*)
 Open Eclipse
 `Help > Install New Software > Add > Archive > Select the Downloaded Plug-in.zip`
in the field "Name" enter "Google Plugin" Click ok.

### Ignore the Warnings, After Competion of Installation, Restart Eclipse.

How to use Google Plugin for Eclipse
    ***File > New > Other > Web > Static Web Project > Enter Project name***
[image: Create New Web Project]

---

***Create New HTML File***

[image: Create New HTML File]

---

***Name to index.html***

### [image: index.html]

***Select Properties of HTML File***

### [image: Set Properties to HTML5]

***Hit Ctrl+Space***

### [image: Cheat Sheet HTML5]

similarly create new *.css file
**Right Click on the css file > Properties > Web Content Settings > Select CSS3 Profile > ok** 
 ***Hit CTRL+Space***
[image: CSS3 Cheat Sheet]
Wooo, Yeah Start Coding.!

Comment: I'm not sure where I missed, but I can't find "Static Web Project" after installed Google Plugin for Eclipse. The only new project type is something about Google App Engine.

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Indigo Service Release 1. Later I tried Aptana plugin, and it works

Comment: It's always better to use latest version of any IDE, you can try Juno JEE for better results

Answer (score 8):

Topstyle 4 is the only one I've com e across with HTML5 (and CSS3) support. Its early stages but it works enough for the most part.

Answer (score 7):

Since HTML5 is still in the works and doesn't have consistant support across any browsers yet, my guess is that it's going to be quite a while before you get a WYSIWYG HTML5 Editor.

In the mean time, get used to editting your markup by hand in a good text editor like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or [TextEdit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextEdit).

Comment: I think you meant s/test/text/ ..

Comment: @jordanstephens - Yes. Really. TextEdit.

Comment: @justin Niessner I mean sure it works, I just wouldn't lump it into a list of "good text editors" To each his own, I suppose...

Comment: @jordanstephens just because TextEdit doesn't have all the fancy features of some other apps doesn't mean it's not good at editing text.

Comment: You are not answering the question

Comment: @Kickaha - The answer, at the time, was no. Of course, the story has changed in the three years since I originally answered the question.

Answer (score 4):

Just to point out, HTML5 *per se* is not "far from ready"; it is actually pretty much finished, "considered by the Working Group to fulfill the relevant requirements of its charter and any accompanying requirements documents." There will be some things to iron out, and the core spec has some accompanying addon bits, but the majority of it is actually ready to use right away, with much of it stable in latest browsers.

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at Atlas: http://280atlas.com/what.php

Answer (score 4):

Adobe Dreamweaver CS5 HTML5 Pack

http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/html5pack/

Answer (score 3):

[NetBeans 7](http://netbeans.org/) has nice support for HTML5. Previously I was a heavy user of Eclipse, but spend more time with NetBeans to play with HTML5 and Servlet.

Answer (score 2):

Coffee Cup Just released one. July 6, 2010
http://www.coffeecup.com/html-editor/

They now also have an OS X version in beta — see also  [this stackoverflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9483569/1209711)

Answer (score 2):

for online solution try maqetta and aloha editor

for offline solution (download-able) try blue griffon

they are free :)
oh yeah, one more, my favorite editor :) and game editor also: construct2

Answer (score 1):

Did research for this at school and as Justing already said. The specification is far from ready, so it wil probably take a while before HTML5 is being supported in editor. Though browsers are busy implementing the parts from the specification that are good enough to be used.

Best you can do is follow blogs, tutorials and other articles on the internet and experiment with developing in HTML5 yourself.

EDIT: Just found an Visual Studio 2008/2010 Plug-in [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d771cbc8-d60a-40b0-a1d8-f19fc393127d)

Answer (score 1):

I must question whether you need, specifically, an editor capable of handling HTML5. It's still HTML. There are changes, yes, but not all that much if you are already comfortable with HTML4. I suspect that most any editor capable of handling HTML should be able to handle HTML5 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Radrails 3 is supposed to have it, Aptana Studio 3 will have it. Radrails is in beta, so thats kind of a downer, but none the less it is there to give'r a whirl.

It is multi-platform too, for those of us non-Windoze fellas.

Answer (score 1):

Try the HTML5 editor written in HTML5 itself

http://www.mobdis.com

Answer (score 1):

[HTML Pencil](http://htmlpencil.appspot.com/) is an online HTML editor created for modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

This might not interest you but just to add (0:, I like [VS2008 IDE](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2009/11/18/html-5-intellisense-and-validation-schema-for-visual-studio-2008-and-visual-web-developer.aspx) for html editing - and it doubles the fun if you have internet explorer developer toolbar (like that of firebug).

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Web Developer Express](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2009/11/18/html-5-intellisense-and-validation-schema-for-visual-studio-2008-and-visual-web-developer.aspx)

Comment: That will give you the HTML5 schema validation, but you still have to edit the markup by hand. I think the OP is looking for a WYSIWYG editor...which Visual Web Developer Express is not (for HTML5).

Answer (score 0):

Check out SproutCore.

http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/10/04/19/sproutcore_debuts_new_html5_web_development_tools.html