# HTML5 fast and small TEXT editor for Windows

Tags: html-editor

My wish is not common, I guess, so I have to ask for recommendations.

I need HTML editor, that:

1. Does NOT support WYSIWYG at all. I write all my code manually and don't want to have an option I don't need.
2. Has rich code completion tools. All tags, attributes AND Javascript methods/properties should be suggested as I type.
3. Has bug-free text coloring.
4. Is small and fast enough to be run on a Eee PC like netbook.
5. Supports MDI tab interface.
6. [Optional] Supports HTML 5 features (new tags, CANVAS methods etc.)

As you see, not at all the most of people need, eh? Not just EASY or SECURED or cool looking... That's why I'm asking you.

Regards,

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637930/any-good-visual-html5-editor-or-ide?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out [E-texteditor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/). It's windows port (or clone I guess you would say?) of TextMate (Mac only). It's definitely feature filled. The few times I've used it, the syntax highlighting was fantastic.

I think it's a great editor because it has support for TextMate snippets/bundles, which bring your text editor to a whole new level. The power that can be extracted from bundles is amazing. It's a pretty easy bundle architecture to develop for also, so if there is something that you can't find, it's very easy to just make yourself. I've made more than a few TextMate bundles myself.