# creating an interface to navigate multimedia files

Tags: interface, multimedia

I have collected many post-modern art videos and images over the years 
and I would like to present to others using an interface, that has an
index with categories of art, artists and on the left with areas showing
the multimedia with the explanation text bellow. I was thinking perhaps
flash (+ actionscript) is the best way to do this since its cross-platform,
but then I thought it could be written in html/css and it will pull out files
from directoris... so dreamweaver might be another way this interface could
be built.

I was wondering if there are applications that makes development of this
interface easier. I appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to develop an application like this using flash, the obvious choices would be Adobe Flash CS5 or Adobe Flash Builder (better for some of the data driven aspects of the application).  Personally I think Flex 4 with Spark would be an excellent choice for someone with previous flash experience (and a CS5 Web Premium license).

On the HTML5/JS side of the house, there are a wealth of great editors and resources for building applications.  Here is a post going over the editors for HTML5 (Aptana is my current IDE of choice for this stuff):

[Any good, visual HTML5 Editor or IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637930/any-good-visual-html5-editor-or-ide)

Now that you have an IDE, you're going to need an HTML5 framework of some sort to make developing the application easier.  Again, there are a lot of options.

- Popcorn.js => http://popcornjs.org/
- Sproutcore => http://www.sproutcore.com/
- Cappuccino => http://cappuccino.org/ (if you're into that whole objective-J kinda thing)

These are just a few options.  This is kind of an open ended question, so I tried to give you a bit of a head start to start asking more questions.

Good luck!

Comment: I also had another concern. I wanted the multimedia files to be 
accessible only through the interface so that no user be able to 
locate the the multimedia files and redistribute online or in 
other places. Is an html browser still a way to do this?

Thanks for the help and introducing great frameworks... I'm 
downloading two of them as we speak.

Comment: unfortunately my mac is too old for sprouts and the other packages are quite complex for my level of knowlege and they are overkill for what i'm trying to acomplish is quite simple: a single page that has has a list of artists and shows thier video/image with a text describing them. Is there an easier way? I is there a flash framework or a ready-made app I can edit?

Comment: I wasn't sure how much programming experience you had :-)  Sadly this is where my knowledge falls off - If you're looking for something easy to use to build the list, you could check out a CMS system?

Comment: I appreciate your help. Exploring this issue further I also discovered http://www.wavemaker.com/