# Is there any IDE/Framework/etc to develop a complex web (RIA like) not using Flex/Flash Builder?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, performance, apache-flex

For a quite long time I was used to use the Flash Builder (previously called "Flex") enviroment to build complex applications, and in my current project (cant say what project is, sory) Im part of a RIA made in Flex, using mxml, AS3, some JS, etc.

The performance is below average.

The site feels like u need a powerful PC to run it something close to smooth.

And Im working with very talented ppl here, or at least thats what I can perceive.

So my question is, there is a posibility that the next version of the website will be made in pure HTML + CSS + JS, to obtain a more responsive feeling when u use the site, is something at least close to what FB can do for you in terms of a project-oriented enviroment?

On another hand, this general laggy and low performance thing is a programmer related issue, or it cant be avoided since "its just Flash" ?

Thanks!

(Im a big fan of flash tbh, but I try to keep my mind open in this)

Comment: -1 from me.  I voted to close as this post reads like flame bait.

Comment: Not at all, but thanks for your comment.

Comment: Agreed, this could have been a useful question, but all the negative comments about Flash Builder are not necessary and severely detract from the real question.

Comment: Ok, sorry for that, Ill edit it.

Comment: @divillysausages, SO is not about negative comments and rants. It's about useful questions and answers.

Comment: I removed my downvote due to the question edit; however I still stand by my vote to close. I could write a book on how to optimize performance of a Flex application; but this question is so generic; it gives us no direction to help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Everything depends on what you're trying to do and if your programmers know how do to their jobs. If they don't take care, then it's very easy to create an application in Flash, and especially Flex (as you really need to know the internals of Flex to understand what it will do and when), that saps memory and power so that you need a beast of a machine to run it. Optimisation is a large topic, but fortunately, the web is covered in links on what not to do, or tips on how to use Flash to it's full potential.

As a quick test, open up the task manager, then run your app (close down all other programs using flash, including gmail, web radio etc), then watch the memory usage. If it's continually climbing, then there's a problem in your code.

Alternatively, if you have a bit more time, build some debug tools into your app so you can see what's going on in terms of framerate and memory usage - try the FlashPreloadProfiler for a quick fix: http://jpauclair.net/flashpreloadprofiler/

If your app shouldn't be complex but it's lagging (by complex, I don't mean the actual purpose of the app, but rather what it's showing on the screen, effects etc), then the problem is that there's misuse somewhere.

Go the HTML5 route if you feel it's the best solution for your site/app, but you'll probably encounter the same problems. In some situations, it's slower, in others Flash wins by a country mile. Again, it comes down to the devs

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was curious about a project oriented ("Flexy") ide to develop an entire solution.

Comment: Your problem doesn't really seem oriented around the IDE - an IDE is just a work environment; it has no effect on the speed of the final product. That said personally I use FlashDevelop (follow the link in Wades post), though there's also FDT: http://www.fdt.powerflasher.com/, Realaxy: http://www.realaxy.com/editor/index and CodeDrive, which plugs into Visual Studio: http://www.codedrive.com/. FlashDevelop is the only one that's free though

Comment: No.. what I want is a way to "port" a project from FB to <insert HTML/JS/CSS robust IDe here>

Comment: in that case, Adobe have a tool called Edge: http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/edge/?promoid=JBDVZ that's meant to help with designing HTML5 animations and Muse: http://muse.adobe.com/ for sites etc, but there's doubts about the quality of the code it produces (it's more of a wysiwyg). the new FDT (http://fdt5.com/) is also meant to have webgl support but it's not available yet. in any case, there's no magical solution to porting your code, you'll need to get your devs to do that

Answer (score 1):

We built Dedoose in Flash Buidler 4, check it out... the performance is freaking great, and it's is a GIANT web app that handles an enormous amount of data.   Flash Player in general does have performance problems, but with great engineering and knowledge of how to squeeze good performance out of it, I personally do not see a better alternative, excerpt for maybe silverlight if your requirements fit.   For guidance on performance improvements a good place to start is all of Grant Skinner's articles over at http://gskinner.com/blog

Additionally, I can't really see what the actual question your asking is, what are the alternatives?  HTML5+CSS is good, but good luck getting any good productivity out of your team developing a large scale web app in it.  Silverlight is pretty dang good if you can force plugins down the users throat, Java is suffers the same dilemna.  Personally I would read up more on getting good performance out of flash, then learn exactly how the flex framework works in terms of what it builts upon flash with, then... if u want real performance, ditch most of the flex framework and use things like MinimalComps and custom built components.     Have you used the Flex Builder Profiler to analyze where your slow downs are occuring?

~ JT

Comment: I have to say, your web-app is amazing, it has a very nice performance. The question was something like: "If I have to make a big web-app project without using FB.. what options do I have if I want the outcome to be HTML based?".

Comment: Hehe thanks! That question makes a lot more sense, but that question has already been asked and answered to death :-P http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637930/any-good-visual-html5-editor-or-ide

Answer (score 0):

If it's just an IDE you want, I'll give a nod to Flash Develop: http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page

Not all the power of Flash (Flex) Builder, and without the design view.  But it's free, open source, and community driven.   I personally prefer the style of context highlighting and code completion hints in Flash Develop.

Comment: Yeah, but a HTML/CSS/JS one :)