# Is there an HTML/CSS/JS editor that immediately shows changes?

Tags: html, editor, editing

I just saw Bret Victors Keynote called "Inventing on Principle". At around 3:34 Minutes he uses a code editor that - after a change he makes - immediately shows consequences of it. As he types there are instant results.

This is the video I am talking about:
http://vimeo.com/36579366

Another example is this [real-time online html editor](http://htmledit.squarefree.com/).

Can you tell me which offline editor I could use to work on my web projects (HTML/CSS/JS) this way? Preferably it can be used on OS X. Thanks!

Comment: You might find [HTML Editor](http://htmleditor.gitlab.io/) handy. It can interact with your file system and works even if you go offline.

Comment: https://codverter.com/src/webeditor - Write HTML, CSS and JavaScript code while viewing web page results in a split screen mode. Web Page view updates automatically while typing. great for scraps, drafts and quick starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there are any free ones, but [TextMate](http://macromates.com) has a live preview window. Just don't download the version 2 beta — I don't think it's been implemented there yet. You can also check out [Coda](http://panic.com/coda/) and [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/).

Comment: Coda does 50% of the trick: I can split it the view of my index.html vertically so it shows both code and output. But if I switch to my style.css it wants me to split the view again. Thats too complex because I have 5-10 files in each projects. _italic_ Best would be if the editor show a list of files and an editor left and the output right.

Comment: How about SnoopCode's live html editor with instant previews.
http://www.snoopcode.com/html/best-html-editor

Answer (score 9):

[Brackets](http://blog.brackets.io/2012/06/25/brackets-open-source-code-editor/) looks nice, but still on development.

Comment: Wow, really looks nice, I'm looking forward to a release

Comment: All of my want. This looks so good

Answer (score 2):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBUC-7D1LIc

this guy already came up with a similar open source program like the one in the video. He also is going to be putting up the source on Github soon.

Answer (score 2):

CoffeeCup has a [Web Editor in beta](http://www.coffeecup.com/osx/web-editor/) that uses live preview and includes the code-preview connection you see in the video. Select an element in the preview and the corresponding HTML/CSS is selected, or select HTML code and see which element it applies to in the preview.

Answer (score 1):

If you're still looking for an *offline* editor, you could always check out Notepad++. It has a live html preview, but doesn't show most of the newer stuff; just basic layouts as well as basic CSS.

[Notepad++ Website](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Espresso updates the preview window as you type in the editor but it's for mac only