# Application for editing and rending HTML side by side?

Tags: html, css, editor

Is there an application that can edit and render and web page side-by-side similar to http://rendera.herokuapp.com/ , but can working "offline" (i.e. can be working even without internet connection).

I tried googling for WYSIWYG HTML editor, but I couldn't come with something similar to http://rendera.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

I found Brackets (http://brackets.io/) somewhat similar to I'm looking for. I managed to find the similar question (different keywords) in StackOverflow ([Is there an HTML/CSS/JS editor that immediately shows changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447216/is-there-an-html-css-js-editor-that-immediately-shows-changes)), so somebody can mark this as duplicate

Answer (score -2):

On windows just point your built-in IIS server to your working directory

> When you edit your html , just refresh the web page

Use Python to serve up your web page from the directory your working in

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

> When you edit your html, just refresh the web page

If using angularjs you can use

```
ng serve
```

> This will load your website normally on localhost:4200 , any change to your code will force a reload of your website

Simply have your browser on one side and your editor on the other.